# Dropping columns by index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello i cannot understand why this command is not working as it should be:

`df.drop(df.columns[index], axis=1, inplace=True)`

index is just a list of integers:

`[1, 2, 8, 9, 15, 16, 22, 23, 29, 30, 36, 37, 43, 44, 50, 51, 57, 58]`

I tried the following command using test data frame which looked like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(27).reshape(3, 9),
              columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'])
```

[image]

And it works just fine. I succesfully dropped columns by index but when I want to use the same command in dataframe created from xlsx file it is not doing anything.

I discovered that when I comment out the line:

`df.set_axis([daty], axis='columns', inplace=True)`

It works just fine, this line is suppoused to change names of all columns to names in list - `daty`

`daty` look like this:

```
['2021-08-08', '2021-08-08', '2021-08-07', '2021-08-07', '2021-08-06', '2021-08-06'] etc.
```

I have no idea how to change names of columns in a way that will not interfere with drop command
or how to modify drop command to work.

I'd really appreciate help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that the below code will make MultiIndex:

```
df=df.set_axis([daty], axis='columns')
#so instead of above code use:
df=df.set_axis(daty, axis='columns')
```

Now Since you have index variable so you can use that with `iloc` accessor for dropping columns even after renaming your column names:

```
df=df.drop(df.iloc[:,index].columns,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code after defining column names ,

```
columns = ['A','B'...]
columns_list = []

for i in columns:
    columns_list.append(columns.index(i))

for index in columns_list:
    df.drop([columns[index]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```